# c/unix: abort process that runs for too long

Tags: c, unix, process

I need to kill such user processes that are taking longer time than a said expected interval on UNIX (Solaris) operating system. This needs to be done inside the process that is currently being executed.

Please suggest how this can be achieved in C or in UNIX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the `alarm()` system call.  It provides you with a `SIGALRM` signal which your process can handle, and use to quit.

Comment: You don't even need to handle it - the default action of `SIGALRM` is to terminate the process.

Comment: I will handle the SIGALRM so as to kill my process gracefully

Answer (score 2):

As long as killing without warning the process in overtime is acceptable, one alternative is to use `ulimit -t <time>` at the time of launching the process.

Answer (score 2):

With `setrlimit`, you can limit the amount of CPU time used by the process. Your process will receive a `SIGXCPU` once the limit is exceeded.

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
struct rlimit limits = {42, RLIM_INFINITY};
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, &limits);
```

Answer (score 0):

At one time I had to solve this exact same problem.

My solution was as follows:

Write a controller program that does the following:

1. Fork a child process that starts the process you want to control.
2. Back in the parent, fork a second child process that sleeps for the maximum time allowed and then exits.
3. In the parent, wait for the children to complete and whichever finishes first causes the parent to kill the other.

Comment: Cute...but I think setrlimit() is more direct.

Comment: Your soultion sounds good, Could you please explain me briefly

Comment: @Sachin:  The trick is to set a signal handler in the parent and depending on the pid of the completed child, either terminate the controlled process or terminate the timer process.  Also after each process has been started, record the child pid and if the the process is a timer process or a worker process.

Comment: These details are abstract. Will be grateful if you can provide an example.

Comment: @Sachin:  An example requires much more space than allowed for a comment.  I suggest that you learn about signal handling and process creation.  Then after you have some semi-working  code, someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score -2):

There's an easier way.  Launch a worker thread to do the work, then call [workerThread.join(timeoutInMS)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) in the main thread.  That will wait for that long.  If that statement returns and the worker thread is still running, then you can kill it and exit.

Comment: Ugh.  My apologies for Stacking too late at night.  Totally misread it.